# Lower Voltage RF Amplifier for 400 MHz

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, rf, amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm using this [Mitsubishi RF amplifer](http://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/hf/sirfpowermod/uhf300-500mlow/uhf300-500mlow_lv4/ra07m4047m.pdf) in a portable device. The Mitsubishi amp operates well between 7V - 9V.

But I have to interface with a power source that gives 1.5V, and stepping 1.5V up to 7V seems like a huge waste.

Are there any RF amps for a 400 MHz signal that operate closer to 1.5V? Or are there any super efficient step up regulators?

Answer (score 2):

**You wont find any 5W RF PA's running at low voltage** let alone ultra LV like 1.5V. So you need a Step-up converter. Lots to choose from. 90% but not at 1.5V.. Look harder for a higher supply voltage.

**Added:**

Is this from a single D cell? I need to know the ESR of the 1.5V sources.
 i.e. the regulation of the voltage with current delta V / delta I.. This is essential.

Also will you have enough power to drive 6W step up converter that can deliver 5W.

http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1254  This is 90% efficient ,  and will deliver 1 Amp in the range 7~9V so exceeds your requirements. Cost It also has dual output capability.

Comment: I bet you have NOT found an efficient 7V 7W up converter yet. some work at lower Voltage and corresponding power levels. WHat is needed? Good Ruck.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used this part because you needed 7 W output. There are all sorts of regulations you need to meet for transmitting at that power. Given your question, I don't think you are up to meeting those requirements.

It's not a huge waste of power to do the step-up. A 7 V requirement isn't unusual for a 7 W amplifier. But for 7 W and 40% efficiency you will need 17.5 W in. It just will be higher current if you start from a lower voltage. It shouldn't be hard to find a switcher that is 80% efficient to go from 1.5 V to 7 V.

Answer (score 0):

DC to DC step-up converters can be found here: http://para.maxim-ic.com/en/search.mvp?fam=stepup&tree=powersupplies